# How to Convert FSharpList back to List in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, list, f#, converters

I have an F# library that returns an FSharpList to my C# caller.

I would now like my C# caller's code to convert this into a List.

What is the most efficient way to do this in C#?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Easier than I thouglt...

Starting with:

```
List<double> niceList= new List<double>();
```

From `List` to `FSharpList` I did this:

```
FSharpList<double> niceSharpList = ListModule.OfSeq(niceList);
```

and to convert back from `FSharpList` to `List` I did:

```
List<double> niceList= niceSharpList.ToList();
```

Comment: Converting from an `FSharpList` to `List` is now `List<double> niceList = new List<double>(ListModule.ToSeq(niceSharpList));` (using FSharp.Core version 4.5.0.0)

Answer (score 0):

To make this work it is essential to add references to the project core F # 4.0

For example in F# you have this

```
/// A list with 3 integers
let listA = [ 1; 2; 3 ]
```

you can use in C# in very simply way

```
List<Int32> listCSHARP = Module1.listA.ToList();

foreach (Int32 i in listCSHARP)
{
     MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
}
```