# int -> int list is not compatible with type int -> IEnumerable<'a>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, f#

Given:

```ml
open System.Linq
```

this is an acceptable expression:

```ml
[2; 3; 4].SelectMany(fun n -> { 1..n })
```

however this is not:

```ml
[2; 3; 4].SelectMany(fun n -> [ 1..n ])
```

The error message says:

```ml
    int -> int list    
is not compatible with type
    int -> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<'a>
```

F# is rejecting the expression because the function is returning an `int list`.

Consider this C# program which does something similar:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace SelectManyCs
{
    class Program
    {
        static List<int> Iota(int n)
        {
            var ls = new List<int>();

            for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) ls.Add(i);

            return ls;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var seq = new List<int>() { 2, 3, 4 };

            foreach (var elt in seq.SelectMany(Iota))
                Console.WriteLine(elt);
        }
    }
}
```

`Iota` returns a `List<int>` and passing it to `SelectMany` is acceptable to C#.

Is the F# behaviour by design or is it bug? If it's by design, why does the similar operation work in C#?

Comment: Just to clarify, the list type used in the C# program is not the same type as the list type used in F#: `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` vs `Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.List<T>`.

Answer (score 9):

This is an expected behavior. C# generally does more automatic conversions between types than F#:

- In C#, the result of the lambda function is `List<T>`, but the C# compiler automatically converts the result to `IEnumerable<T>`, which is the expected return type of the function.
- In F#, the compiler does not automatically cast the result to `IEnumerable<T>` and so your second snippet does not type check - because it is returning `list<T>` which is a different type than the expected `IEnumerable<T>` (you can cast list to enumerable, but they are different types).

The F# library defines its own version of the `SelectMany` operation called `Seq.collect`. The F# function has the following type:

```
> Seq.collect;;
val it : (('a -> #seq<'c>) -> seq<'a> -> seq<'c>)
```

Here, the type `#seq<'c>` explicitly says that the result can be of any type that can be converted to `seq<'c>` (this is what the `#` in the name means). This is why the [answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23315615/calling-ienumerable-selectmany/23315699#23315699) works:

```
[2; 3; 4] |> Seq.collect (fun n -> [ 1..n ])
```

Comment: Is it appropriate to say that "the C# compiler automatically converts the result to `IEnumerable<T>`"? Since the `List` class implements `IEnumerable`, it a `List` *is* effectively an `IEnumerable`, so no conversion is necessary.

Comment: The [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370372.aspx) indicate that F# `List` implements `IEnumerable`. So no cast or conversion should be necessary.

Comment: @dharmatech You're right - it just _casts_ the list to `IEnumerable<T>` (rather than doing any conversions). But even the casting is only done automatically in certain cases...

Comment: In the expression `[2;3;4].SelectMany(...)`, `SelectMany` (defined on `IEnumerable`) is being directly called on an F# list with no cast or conversion. So I think the design is inconsistent here. :-)

Comment: The F# compiler does the casting automatically only on parameters of a method (including the instance parameter). So it is a bit inconsistent, but in a good way :-) it allows this in most important cases without making things too hard for type inference...

Comment: Aha... your note about the `#` in `#seq<'c>` let me to read about [Flexible Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233198.aspx) in the F# docs. I didn't know about this annotation. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

F# `int list` is very different from C# `List<int>`. If you wanted to use the type from C#,  F# list is immutable (it cannot be changed after the list was created). On the other hand, in the first (working) example, you are returning a `seq<int>`, which is basically same as `IEnumerable<int>`. 
F# `list` implements `IEnumerable` as well, but interfacing in F# works a bit differently: If you want to pass some argument as a specific interface, you need to explicitly cast it to that interface instance. That means, this would work as well:

```
let y = 
    [2; 3; 4].SelectMany(fun n -> [ 1..n ] :> IEnumerable<int>)
```

Alternatively, it is possible to convert F# `list` to `IEnumerable<>` using `Seq.ofList`:

```
[2; 3; 4].SelectMany(fun n -> (Seq.ofList [ 1..n ]))
```

The other difference is explicit interfacing in F#: 
Some other details on conversions from F# list to `System.Collections.Generic.List<>` can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18562007/convert-fsharplist-back-to-list-in-c-sharp).

Comment: `System.Collections.Generic.List` is indeed very different from F# lists, but that difference has nothing to do with the problem here. Using `System.Collections.Generic.List` in F# would behave exactly the same here as using F# lists and would require the same "conversion" to work. Note that F# lists implement seq (aka IEnumerable) just like .net lists do.

Comment: @sepp2k I improved the answer to make this point a bit clearer.